# Identify Ubuntu/Debian package that a binary belongs to based on its md5sum

Tags: package-management, deb, md5sum

Is it possible to identify the Debian package that a binary belongs to based on its `md5sum`.

All Debian packages contain a `md5sums` file that list all the files and their corresponding `md5sum`.
So, I am wondering, giveν an `md5sum` of a binary or any file, whether it is possible to get the package info that it belongs to.

Debian already provides an [API](https://sources.debian.org/doc/api/#sources) to search for source packages based on `sha256sum` of any source file it contains.

In my case, if I have a binary, say `libxml2.so.2.9.4`, I want to know its origin package by simply searching for its `md5sum`.

Comment: Why not use `dpkg -S  libxml2.so.2.9.4`? That will give you the package name, `dpkg -L <packagename>` will list all the files in that package.

Comment: Problem is, these binaries are not obtained from installed packages. I am reversing some firmware and I want to know their origin. All I know is the firemware that I am reversing is using Debian distro. So, I am trying to identify the packages installed in the firmware